# Im trying to make a welcome message by sending a dm to the user but im getting a "guild_id1 is not defined" error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is the code for it below.
The error is,
"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 11, in 
stored_guild_ids = (guild_id1, guild_id2, guild_id3, guild_id4)
NameError: name 'guild_id1' is not defined"

```
#below are the server id's.
guild_id1=[730922649144000602]
guild_id2=[821556171735040020]
guild_id3=[757014581984886856]
guild_id4=[830182875454373948]

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member: discord.Member):
    if member.guild.id1 in stored_guild_ids:
        await member.send(f"Welcome {member.name}! We are glad to have you here! Please make sure you pick your roles if needed/wanted! Have a great day!")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member: discord.Member):
    if member.guild.id2 in stored_guild_ids:
        await member.send(f"Welcome {member.name}! We are glad to have you here! Please make sure you pick your roles if needed/wanted! Have a great day!")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member: discord.Member):
    if member.guild.id3 in stored_guild_ids:
        await member.send(f"Welcome {member.name}! We are glad to have you here! Please make sure you pick your roles if needed/wanted! Have a great day!")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member: discord.Member):
    if member.guild.id4 in stored_guild_ids:
        await member.send(f"Welcome {member.name}! We are glad to have you here! Please make sure you pick your roles if needed/wanted! Have a great day!")
```

ALSO, is this the correct code to make the bot DM the user said message or no?

Comment: The string quotes don't match, you have multiple syntax errors.

Comment: You need not use `on_member_join` 4 times. Add all the conditions inside one single function. My answer has the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in the use of `on_member_join` function 4 times. This is not how it works. You have to define this function only once and then all the stuff you want to do in it. Add all the conditions and loops and all inside.

So firstly we would keep those variables outside the function as you did. If you want to use them only in this function then you want add it inside the function but for now I would keep them outside.

```
guild_id1=[730922649144000602]
guild_id2=[821556171735040020]
guild_id3=[757014581984886856]
guild_id4=[830182875454373948]
```

Now, we will create the `event` of member joining. This can be done just like you did above. We would define it only once and then impose all conditions inside it.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member: discord.Member):
```

So, we are done with the variables and the event. Now, we will first create the conditions. These will be according to your code. I will be using `if`, `elif` and `else` for this.

```
if member.guild.id1 in stored_guild_ids:
    await member.send(f"Welcome {member.name}! We are glad to have you here! Please make sure you pick your roles if needed/wanted! Have a great day!")

elif member.guild.id2 in stored_guild_ids:
    await member.send(f"Welcome {member.name}! We are glad to have you here! Please make sure you pick your roles if needed/wanted! Have a great day!")

elif member.guild.id3 in stored_guild_ids:
    await member.send(f"Welcome {member.name}! We are glad to have you here! Please make sure you pick your roles if needed/wanted! Have a great day!")

elif member.guild.id4 in stored_guild_ids:
    await member.send(f"Welcome {member.name}! We are glad to have you here! Please make sure you pick your roles if needed/wanted! Have a great day!")

else:
    pass
```

I have added `pass` to else statement because we do not need anything to be performed here. Using this condition set we can now do what we want to.

Let's now add it to the `event` function we had created.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member: discord.Member):
    if member.guild.id1 in stored_guild_ids:
        await member.send(f"Welcome {member.name}! We are glad to have you here! Please make sure you pick your roles if needed/wanted! Have a great day!")

    elif member.guild.id2 in stored_guild_ids:
        await member.send(f"Welcome {member.name}! We are glad to have you here! Please make sure you pick your roles if needed/wanted! Have a great day!")

    elif member.guild.id3 in stored_guild_ids:
        await member.send(f"Welcome {member.name}! We are glad to have you here! Please make sure you pick your roles if needed/wanted! Have a great day!")

    elif member.guild.id4 in stored_guild_ids:
        await member.send(f"Welcome {member.name}! We are glad to have you here! Please make sure you pick your roles if needed/wanted! Have a great day!")

    else:
        pass
```

Now we have created a function with the necessary conditions.

Now, here is the complete code with the changes I have made.

```
guild_id1=[730922649144000602]
guild_id2=[821556171735040020]
guild_id3=[757014581984886856]
guild_id4=[830182875454373948]

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member: discord.Member):
    if member.guild.id1 in stored_guild_ids:
        await member.send(f"Welcome {member.name}! We are glad to have you here! Please make sure you pick your roles if needed/wanted! Have a great day!")

    elif member.guild.id2 in stored_guild_ids:
        await member.send(f"Welcome {member.name}! We are glad to have you here! Please make sure you pick your roles if needed/wanted! Have a great day!")

    elif member.guild.id3 in stored_guild_ids:
        await member.send(f"Welcome {member.name}! We are glad to have you here! Please make sure you pick your roles if needed/wanted! Have a great day!")

    elif member.guild.id4 in stored_guild_ids:
        await member.send(f"Welcome {member.name}! We are glad to have you here! Please make sure you pick your roles if needed/wanted! Have a great day!")

    else:
        pass
```

---

Hope I could explain it and Hope you understood. If you still have any problem please ask comment on the answer! I would gladly help! :)

Thank You! :D

Comment: So i tried this and whenever someone joines the server ( i tried server id2) the bot does not dm them. I also don't get an error message either.